# Convertir de int a char en C

Tags: c, cast

Mi pregunta es acerca de cómo convertir de int a char en lenguaje C. Es el equivalente a hacer en C#:

```
int a = 97;
char b = (char)a;
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Es muy similar a tu ejemplo, en realidad en c el tipo de dato char es un valor numérico, lo puedes ver en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int a = 97;
char b = (char)a;
printf("%c", a);
```

El resultado será "a" igual que en tu ejemplo.